# Form Validation with ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I have a general validation method *validateFields* for my application. The script will check every field that needs to be validated against several conditions and increment the counter.

```
if(validate_for_nil(field) == true){
  // return true and continue other validations
} else { 
  //stop further actions and raise error
}
if(validate_max_chars(field) == true){
  //continue other validations
}else{
  //stop and raise error
}
```

Similarly for uniqueness validation, I need to send an ajax request. But the problem is, my function is not waiting for the ajax response.It will check the condition with *undefined* as ajax response.How can I make my entire function to wait till the ajax response comes? Async:false in ajax request is not convenient for me. Please help
Here is my code:

```
function form_validation() {
   $("[data-required=true]:visible").each(function(){
      element = $(this); 
      errors = validate_fields(element);
      total_errors = total_errors + errors;
  }) 
  if(total_errors == 0) {
     //submit form
  }else{
    //do nothing
  }
}

function validate_fields(field) {
   error = 0
   if(validate_for_nil(field) == true){
      // return true and continue other validations
   } else {
     error = error+1
     raise_error()
   }
   if(validate_max_chars(field) == true){
      //continue other validations
   }else{
      //counter increment and raise error
   }
   if(validate_uniqueness(field) == true) { // this method calls an AJAX request
     // return true
   }else {
      // counter increment and raise error 
   }
}
```

Comment: Use **[.deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/)** / **[deffered object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax success/error function(s):

```
$.ajax({ cache: false,
    url: "some url",
    data: {  },
    success: function (data) {
       //do stuff here
    },
    error: function (ajaxContext) {
        alert(ajaxContext.responseText)
    }
});
```

Comment: actually I am sending the success response to some other function. But that function is not waiting for this response to execute and I cannot change the flow as there are many other functions using the same

Comment: you want that validate_fields() to be called after ajax complete?

Comment: I want the validate_fields to wait till validate_uniqueness() gives a response other than undefined

Comment: why don't you move validate_fields() to success: function (data) of AJAX

Comment: There can be cases where uniqueness check is not necessary. For that fields, all the other checks should be performed

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to do that much of hardword, just let the 3rd party plugin to handle all the client side validation itself

i would recommend

https://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/

JqBootstrapValidation

1. Free to use
2. Helps with all validations
3. Custom validations such as (min,max,maxcheck,mincheck,email regex, etc)
4. calls your ajax only if client validation succeeds (success method callback)
5. many more benefits

once all the client side validation is done by the plugin, use the ajax call to handle duplication checks, uniqueness, etc etc etc.